# How to solve 'invalid repo name' Git error?

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

I've installed Gitolite, just like said in GitLab instructions, til now it was all ok, repo's created... but when tried to clone or push, it returns NO repo found - or something similar.

But when I set my remote to the full path like `git@server:22/~git/repositories/repo.git` it clones, but when try to push, its caught an error:

```
git push origin master
ERROR: invalid repo name.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What can it be?

Comment: No, =\, I've already seen this one ... the error is diferent, anyway thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message comes from "[`gitolite-shell.parse_soc()`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L139-L150)"

```
sub parse_soc {
    my $soc = $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND};
    $soc ||= 'info';

    my $git_commands = "git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack|git-upload-archive";
    if ( $soc =~ m(^($git_commands) '/?(.*?)(?:\.git(\d)?)?'$) ) {
        my ( $verb, $repo, $trace_level ) = ( $1, $2, $3 );
        $ENV{D} = $trace_level if $trace_level;
        _die "invalid repo name: '$repo'" if $repo !~ $REPONAME_PATT;
        trace( 2, "git command", $soc );
        return ( $verb, $repo );
    }
```

With [`REPONAME_PATT`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L51) being:

```
$REPONAME_PATT = qr(^\@?[0-9a-zA-Z][-0-9a-zA-Z._\@/+]*$);
```

A gitolite address shouldn't include any path, like so:

```
git@server:22/repo
```

Instead of `git@server:22/~git/repositories/repo.git`, this issue is [described here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts.html#ybpfail):

> Consider `git@server:repositories/reponame.git`.
>   The clone operation will work -- you're using the full Unix path, (assuming default `$REPO_BASE` setting), and so the shell finds the repo where you said it would be.
>   However, when you push, gitolite's update hook kicks in, and fails to run because some of the environment variables it is expecting are not present.