# git push error message

Tags: git, perl, gitolite

I installed gitolite and git server in linux.
I created repository, push anythings.

"git push" is succeed. because I succeed add new user.
but It show error.
is this,

[image]

> remote: FATAL: invalid repo ''

what is this?
I checked this answers,  [Gitolite refuses to accept commits to gitolite-admin.git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847483/gitolite-refuses-to-accept-commits-to-gitolite-admin-git). but unsolved.

I want to clear this error.

and, This error is not only 1 repository but also all of repositories show. This error is not only 1 user but also all of user show.

I chekced 
[How to solve 'invalid repo name' Git error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396853/how-to-solve-invalid-repo-name-git-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I don't understand.

```
_die "invalid repo name: '$repo'" if $repo !~ $REPONAME_PATT;
```

will be work only  `$soc =~ m(^($git_commands) '?/?(.*?)'?$)` is true.
maybe $soc is "git push". and $git_commands is "git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack|git-upload-archive".

so, My question seems to have nothing to do with that answer.
I don't know about perl. If I wrong that, please help me.

Comment: How do you know '"git push" is succeed'? Also you forgot to mention the remote repo like 'origin' and the branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396853/how-to-solve-invalid-repo-name-git-error?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Najam I agree ;) (having written that post)

Comment: @Shubham Naik
because, I succeed add new user.

Comment: Adding a new user, and pushing an incorrect conf/gitolite.conf (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/) file are two different things: you can add successfuly a new public key, creating a new user, while your gitolite.conf might still be incorrect.

Comment: Yet another person who thinks it's useful to post images of text. I will never understand this. Why do you do it?

Comment: If you think it's not a duplicate of the linked question, update your question to include your configuration